# My WEBI report is sorting numbers from source Excel sheet in a binary style

Tags: excel, numbers, webi

I'm  new to WEBI (self taught at work) and am currently having some trouble. I'm running a report from an Excel spreadsheet, where column A is numbers from 1-49.

It looks fine in the query preview window, but when I run the query the numbers default to a

1,10,11,2,20,21,22 kind of sequence.

Has anyone experienced this before?

I've had a look at the Excel spreadsheet and there doesn't seem to be anything untoward there. I've tried the Sort function in WEBI sheet but it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Web Intelligence will automatically sort in ascending order beginning with left most column of your table. It seems to me that your object is a string (not a number) and therefore is being sorted alphabetically rather than numerically.

Create a variable and use the [ToNumber()](https://help.sap.com/doc/4aaf4f888c884bd99ef48581c5a241c6/4.3.2/en-US/context.htm?contextid=353) function to convert your string to a number.

```
=ToNumber([Some String])
```

Then your values will sort numerically.

[image]